# How can I turn on tabbing bars in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[this is how my vscode is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Wad.png)

[This is what im looking for to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6eEp.png)

What is the name of the option that I have to enable? I think I disabled it not meaning to do it. I tried looking for the setting but didnt manage to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following:

```json
"editor.guides.indentation": true
```